# magento 2.4 setup is not displaying, showing the page isn't working, HTTP error 500

Tags: setup, http-error-500, magento2.4

magento 2.4 setup is not displaying, showing the page isn't working HTTP error 500, but i tried with simple php code.server is working fine. what may be the error, i am using php 7.3
[image]

Comment: Admin and forntend both are same error show??

Comment: still i am not installed magento to open admin panel

Comment: i just put all the magento files in /var/www/html directory

Comment: Can you provide the error message from the server logs?

Comment: add ini_set("display_errors", 1); code into your project root folder index.php file. So, it will show you an error. Also please make sure if your project mode is "developer".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing imap extension
sudo apt-get install php7.3-imap && sudo apt-get install php-xml